# ACF - Getting a gallery from a Custom Post Type

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to display a gallery from a custom post type.

I created a new Custom Post Type using Custom Post Type UI plugin and called it 'photo'.

My ACF Custom Field is called 'gallery'.

This is a one pager website so I am trying to display the images from the index.php.

I started with the following code which worked fine when the gallery was included on a regular Post page:

```
<?php

$images = get_field('gallery');

if( $images ): ?>

        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>

                     <div class="item" ><img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['large']; ?>"  /></div>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I am now trying to pull images form a custom post type like this:

```
<?php

   $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'photo') );
     while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

$images = get_field('gallery');

if( $images ): ?>

        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>

                         <div class="item" ><img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['large']; ?>"  /></div>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

But this does not work- in fact, the whole page turns blank like when syntax is wrong.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the endwhile - guess that's why your page goes blank.